# sqlalchemy insert from select is losing correct types for columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using a temp table to add records to from a pandas dataframe, which I then insert into the final table with the below query

```
result = connection.execute("INSERT INTO finalTable SELECT * FROM tempTable ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING")
```

This will give me type errors as all columns now are of type string somehow:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column
>   "column3" is of type integer but expression is of type text

Even though the columns in the temp table have the same types as in the final table. 
When I assign the types in the select query as below it works fine.

```
result = connection.execute("INSERT INTO finalTable SELECT column1, TO_DATE(column2, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), CAST(column3 as int) FROM tempTable ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING")
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a more generic way to make sure the correct types are preserved?

Comment: Can you also add the error messages?

Comment: @JimJones added the error message I get when not casting column3 to int in the select query.

Comment: if column3 of temptable is set to be text and the target column is of type int, I see no way around it. You have to either change the type of the source table or cast the text column as you've been doing, a more compact way of casting is adding `::`, e.g. `column3::int`.

Comment: I now see my statement about types was lost in the question. The types of the columns is exactly the same in the temp table as in the final table

Comment: In this case the error has to be somewhere in sqlalchemy - which I'm not familiar with :) The postgres part should work fine, e.g. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id INT, txt TEXT);  
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (1,'foo'),(1,'bar');  

CREATE TABLE target (id INT PRIMARY KEY, txt TEXT);  
INSERT INTO target SELECT * FROM tmp 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

SELECT * FROM target;` Good luck!